# Calling to data object function on upload (SilverStripe)

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a DataObject class called `AdminUpload` that stores two variables: `UploadDate` (which is always going to bet set to the current date) and `Total`, which is an int.

The function `updateUploads()` is called and stores the current date and increments the `Total` by 1 each time its called.

```
<?php

class AdminUpload extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'UploadDate' => 'Date',
        'Total' => 'int'
    );

    // Tell the datagrid what fields to show in the table
    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'ID' => 'ID',
        'UploadDate' => 'Current Date',
        'Total' => 'Version Number'
    );

    public function updateUploads(){
        $uploadDate = SS_Datetime::now();
        $this->UploadDate = $uploadDate;
        $this->Total++;//increment the value currently stored in the database each time

        $this->write();
    }
```

}

What I want to to is, when someone uploads a new image in the admin view, then the `updateCache()` function is called during the `onAfterWrite()` process. I only want to maintain one entry in the database, though, so every time I upload an image, I want to have just one entry in the `AdminUpload` database table.

```
public function onAfterWrite(){
        $updateGallery = parent::onAfterWrite();

        $adminUploading = AdminUpload::get();
        $adminUploading -> updateUploads();

        return $updateGallery;
    }
```

I've never tried to do a function call in SilverStripe like this--it seems simple enough but since I am not going to add a new entry to the database with each call to the updateUploads() function, that's where I'm stuck. Any tips would be helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is incorrect approach to create a whole table for just one record. If you were going to use theses two fields on a page, then adding them to that page (create a new page type) would be a better idea.

If you are talking about file uploads, then you can always query this information directly from database.

```
$uploadedFilesCount = File::get()->count();
$lastUploadedFileDate = File::get()->sort('CreatedDate', 'DESC')->first()->CreatedDate;
```

`onAfterWrite` is a hook and used from `DataExtension`. There are cases when hooks are called directly on DO and then on extensions.

Your extension code might look like this to handle 'onCreated' state:

```
class UploadsCounter extends DataExtension {
    protected $isCreating = false;

    public function onBeforeWrite() {
       if (!$this->owner->isInDB()) {
           $this->isCreating = true;
       }
    }

    // called on validation or database error
    public function onAfterSkippedWrite() {
        $this->isCreating = false;
    }

    public function onAfterWrite() {
        if (!$this->isCreating) return;

        $this->isCreating = false;
        $adminUploading = AdminUpload::get()->first();

        if (!$adminUploading ) {
            $adminUploading = new AdminUpload();
            $adminUploading->write();
        }

        $adminUploading->updateUploads();
    }
}
```

You should define `UploadsCounter` extension on the dataobject that you are going to count, for example:

mysite/_config/config.yml

```
File:
  extensions:
    - UploadsCounter
```